# Exclude React from webpack-ed component library

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm, webpack

I'm trying to set up my project so I can have a common library that is then used by two different wep-apps. All apps use React and I'm working on breaking out a part of the first web-app I've gotten working into it's own library, the common library.

So far,

- I've created two npm packages, `software/library` and `software/app1`.
- `library` has webpack and babel setup.
- I've ran `npm link ../library` from inside `software/app1`.

Now I'm still getting the message:

> 1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
> 2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
> 3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app

It seems like webpack and babel are working correctly because `app1` can see `../library`, but `library`'s React must be conflicting with `app1`'s copy.

*ran in app1*

```
npm ls react
app1@0.1.0 /software/app1
├─┬ @testing-library/react@11.2.7
│ └── react@17.0.2 deduped
├─┬ react-dom@17.0.2
│ └── react@17.0.2 deduped
├─┬ react-router-dom@5.3.0
│ ├─┬ react-router@5.2.1
│ │ ├─┬ mini-create-react-context@0.4.1
│ │ │ └── react@17.0.2 deduped
│ │ └── react@17.0.2 deduped
│ └── react@17.0.2 deduped
├─┬ react-serialize@0.2.0
│ └── react@17.0.2 deduped invalid
├── react@17.0.2 invalid
└─┬ theme@1.0.0 -> /software/theme
  ├─┬ react-dom@16.14.0
  │ └── react@16.14.0 deduped
  └── react@16.14.0

npm ERR! code ELSPROBLEMS
npm ERR! invalid: react@17.0.2 software/app1/node_modules/react
```

I know it can't be a React Hook problem because when `library` was part of `app1`'s source, the hooks inside it worked fine.

I'll post my `library/package.json` and `library/webpack.config.js`.

#### package.json

```json
{
    "babel": {
    "presets": [
        "@babel/env",
        "@babel/react"
    ]
    },
    "type": "module",
    "name": "library",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "description": "common library",
    "author": "John Smith",
    "main": "./dist/index.js",
    "module": "./dist/index.modern.js",
    "source": "./src/index.js",
    "engines": {
        "node": ">=10"
    },
    "peerDependencies": {
        "react": "^16.14.0",
        "react-dom": "^16.13.1",
        "react-scripts": "^3.4.1"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "@babel/cli": "^7.16.0",
        "@babel/core": "^7.16.0",
        "@babel/preset-env": "^7.16.4",
        "@babel/preset-react": "^7.16.0",
        "babel-eslint": "^10.0.3",
        "babel-loader": "^8.1.0",
        "babel-plugin-transform-react-jsx": "^6.24.1",
        "cross-env": "^7.0.2",
        "css-loader": "^3.4.2",
        "eslint": "^6.8.0",
        "eslint-config-prettier": "^6.7.0",
        "eslint-config-standard": "^14.1.0",
        "eslint-config-standard-react": "^9.2.0",
        "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.18.2",
        "eslint-plugin-node": "^11.0.0",
        "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^3.1.1",
        "eslint-plugin-promise": "^4.2.1",
        "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.17.0",
        "eslint-plugin-standard": "^4.0.1",
        "file-loader": "^4.3.0",
        "gh-pages": "^2.2.0",
        "html-webpack-plugin": "^4.0.0-beta.11",
        "microbundle-crl": "^0.13.10",
        "npm-run-all": "^4.1.5",
        "prettier": "^2.0.4",
        "react": "^16.14.0",
        "react-dom": "^16.13.1",
        "react-scripts": "^3.4.1",
        "style-loader": "^0.23.1",
        "url-loader": "^2.3.0",
        "webpack": "^4.42.0",
        "webpack-cli": "^4.9.1",
        "webpack-dev-server": "^3.11.0",
        "webpack-node-externals": "^3.0.0"
    },
    "files": [
        "dist"
    ]
}
```

#### webpack.config.js

```js
import nodeExternals from 'webpack-node-externals';
import path from 'path';
import fs from 'fs';

const PACKAGE = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync('./package.json'));
const APPNAME = PACKAGE['name'];

export default {
    // entry:'./src/index.js',
    output:{
    path:path.resolve('dist'),
    // filename:'webpack-' + APPNAME + '.js',
    filename:APPNAME + '.js',
    library:APPNAME
    },

    entry: PACKAGE['source'],
    mode: "development",
    externals:[nodeExternals()],
    module: {
    rules: [
        {
        test: /\.m?js$/,
        exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
        use: {
            loader: "babel-loader"
        }
        },
        {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: [
            "style-loader",
            {
            loader: "css-loader",
            options: {
                modules: true
            }
            }
        ]
        },
        {
        test: /\.(png|svg|jpg|gif)$/,
        use: ["file-loader"]
        }
    ]
    }
};
```

I've been working on this problem for the past day without any solution. So far I've tried:

- Only having library's React be a peerDependency and devDependency.
- Adding webpack external

It all doesn't seem to make a difference. I think at first it wasn't working because I didn't have babel setup, but now it's still including library's React and not working.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up nuking my `package.json` and replaced webpack with rollup. For some reason, webpack just wasn't taking the instruction to exclude React and I could find how to disable React's inclusion. It seems strange that webpack didn't work, but I actually am using `library` in `app1` now. This is what worked.

#### config.babel.js

```js
module.exports = {
    presets:[
        "@babel/preset-env",
        "@babel/preset-react"
    ]
};
```

#### rollup.config.js

```js
import babel from 'rollup-plugin-babel';
import postcss from 'rollup-plugin-postcss';

const config = [
    {
    input:'src/index.js',
    output:{
        file:'dist/index.esm.js',
        format:'esm',
    },
    external:['react'],
    plugins:[
         postcss({
      plugins: []
         }),
        babel({ exclude:"node_modules/**" }),
    ],
    }
];

export default config;
```

#### package.json

```json
{
    "devDependencies": {
        "@babel/cli": "^7.16.0",
        "@babel/core": "^7.16.0",
        "@babel/preset-env": "^7.16.4",
        "@babel/preset-react": "^7.16.0",
        "postcss": "^8.3.11",
        "rollup-plugin-babel": "^4.4.0",
        "rollup-plugin-postcss": "^4.0.1"
    },
    "name": "theme",
    "module": "dist/index.esm.js",
    "files": [
        "dist"
    ],
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "scripts": {
        "build": "rollup -c"
    },
    "keywords": [],
    "author": "",
    "license": "ISC",
    "description": ""
}
```

This answer doesn't answer the question, but it is what I ended up getting to work. If someone knows what was going on with webpack and why it wasn't working they should post that as well.

Comment: downvoted since the solution was to just abandon a framework and use a different framework.

Answer (score 1):

You have React in both `peerDependencies`, and `devDependencies`.

Remove React from your `devDependencies` property in `package.json`, delete your `node_modules` directory, and run `npm install`.

Comment: This did not work. Deleted library's package-lock and npm_modules, removed from package.json, and ran npm install. still in app1, it's saying "You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
You might have more than one copy of React in the same app"

Comment: Have you reviewed this yet regarding the rules of hooks? https://legacy.reactjs.org/warnings/invalid-hook-call-warning.html